# Proof by contradiction(sets)

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I am stuck with this question.

How to prove that compliments of a universal set is the null set by contradiction?

Comment: So assume it is not the null set and see if you can get a contradiction. What does it mean for a set to *not* be the null set?

Comment: Note by the way that there is only one null set (I edited the question and changed `a` to `the` null set).

Answer (score 0):

Suppose the complement of the universal set is not empty.

Then the complement of the universal set has at least one element.  Let $x$ be an element of the the complement.

But $x$ exists. so it *is* in the universal set.

So $x$ can not be in the complement of the universal set.

==== oops, old answer: I didn't realize you specifically wanted a prove by contradiction=====

It should follow directly by definitions.

If $U$ is the universal set, then $A^c = \{x\in U| x\not \in A\}=\{x| x \in U,$ and $x \in A\}$.

So by definition $U^c = \{x\in U| x\not \in U\}=\{x| x\in U, x \not \in U\} = \emptyset$.